# Getting this error while trying BDD cucumber Selenium when designing Page object model

Tags: javascript, eclipse, cucumber, cucumber-junit, picocontainer

> Exception in thread "main" cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: cucumber.runtime.java.picocontainer.PicoFactory.addClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)V
>       at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.addStepDefinition(JavaBackend.java:154)
>       at cucumber.runtime.java.MethodScanner.scan(MethodScanner.java:68)
>       at cucumber.runtime.java.MethodScanner.scan(MethodScanner.java:41)
>       at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.loadGlue(JavaBackend.java:86)
>       at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.(Runtime.java:91)
>       at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.(Runtime.java:69)
>       at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.(Runtime.java:65)
>       at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:35)
>       at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
>   Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: cucumber.runtime.java.picocontainer.PicoFactory.addClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)V
>       at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.addStepDefinition(JavaBackend.java:149)
>       ... 8 more

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It will help you craft solid questions that will (hopefully) yield good answers. And you should include the minimal amount of code that demonstrates your issue and what you've done to solve it.

Comment: That is not one of the best Stack Overflow questions I've seen. My tip is to treat your question as if it were a bug: what happens, what should happen, what did you do (enough info to reproduce it). You can do better.

Comment: sure. i am new to this. will learn to do better

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that cucumber cannot find your glue libraries. The commandline runner is in the stack trace which suggests that you are not following the syntax rules for CLI.  Here is an example:

```
mvn clean test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @search --monochrome --plugin pretty:STDOUT --plugin html:target/cucumber-html-report --plugin json:target/cucumber.json --glue steps --glue runsupport classpath:features"
```

Note the double dash characters before keywords. Also notice that since there are two glue paths that there are two --glue clauses. Also note that only the package name of the two -glue paths were specified.

Further note that STDOUT needed to be specified on --plugin pretty:STDOUT.

Finally note that the features keyword was dropped completely. The path specified at the end (without a keyword) tells cucumber-jvm where to find the feature files.

Be warned, if you get any of this wrong then cucumber-jvm gives you cryptic error messages with which you have first hand knowledge. The usage is explained [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/0aecc4d3e4c15fc34b63f848043deba2c230e35f/core/src/main/resources/cucumber/api/cli/USAGE.txt).

BTW, claspath: refers to, in this case, the Maven default classpath which for features is

```
src/test/resources/
```

If you want help in the future post the minimum code necessary to reproduce the problem.  Remember that your brain is not a network connected device.  :-)

Comment: The Maven default classpath for step definitions is src/test/java

Comment: PS. PicoContainer could also be a problem but you didn't mention dependency injection.  If you are using [dependency injection](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/java-di) then let us know.